# Making a lock screen UI similar to the Apple Map app in nav mode?

Tags: ios, api, background, lockscreen

I have been googling and can't seem to find any info on how to make anything more than a widget app for when an iOS device is on the lock screen.  HOWEVER.... then I see the Nav mode for Apple's map app and it taunts me.
I want to make a app that works very similarly for recording a path taken.

Unfortunately I can find anyone talking about how to replicate that behavior.  Could someone tell me:

A) If it's possible or locked down for 1st party apple apps only.

B) Where do I find a example app that I can learn from?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple apps can do things that developer apps can't.  This is one of those things.  You can use Core Location in the background to record a path, but you can't show it on the lock screen.

Comment: That was kind of what I was afraid of.  I know apple has a vision of the iPad being it's next computing platform, but until they start giving developers more control they are at risk of losing their market share.